# C# Charts and Graphs Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

I know there are stock charts and graphs for C# with Windows Forms. However I have been looking into Telerik and I really like their style, I just don't want to spend $1000 for the software. Are there are any alternatives to Telerik that offer similar design types. I am just trying to avoid stock designs which are low quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a chart support in .netframework 3.5 and 4.0 have you looked at the

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

it basically creates all the kind of charts for you and it free

here are couple of useful links

http://www.dotnetperls.com/chart

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168056/Windows-Charting-Application

Comment: So I can use `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` for all my charting. I just have to play around with to get the scheme I want. Would I be able to customize the charts like Telerik charts?